# NullIfZero in Snowflake

Tags: sql, teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to migrate Teradata Queries to Snowflake.

I'm dividing by a value that I need to cast as Null if the value is zero to avoid Divide by Zero errors, is there a function/syntax for this?

```
Balance/NULLIFZERO(Limit) AS UTILIZATION,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Balance/NULLIF(Limit, 0)
```

Btw, `nullifzero` is very old legacy syntax, Standard SQL's `nullif` should be used in Teradata, too.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [14.07.2020](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/4-24-Release-Notes-July-14-15-2020) Snowflake natively supports [NULLIFZERO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullifzero.html)

> Returns NULL if the argument evaluates to 0; otherwise, returns the argument.
>
> ```
> NULLIFZERO( <expr> )
> ```